# Including php variable in header()

Tags: php, variables, header

I'm still learning php and I still haven't figured out when to use ' or ". I'm guessing thats the problem with this code. It redirects me to the right page but the $loc variable isn't carried over.

```
 <?php header("Location: roomdata.php?loc=$loc"); ?>
```

on the page that has the header() commaned I also have an include command...

```
<?php  include 'include/globalscripts.php';  ?>
```

and in the globalscripts.php is...

```
<?php if( isset($_GET['loc']))?>

<?php $loc = $_GET["loc"];?>
```

Comment: Add more info like what the $loc is and how you derive it, code looks fine, the problem could be in how you construct $loc

Comment: Read about [strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax) so you will know the difference between single and double quotes.  Likely that isn't your issue as that syntax is correct.  Maybe `$loc` isn't in the scope where you run that code.

Comment: @techouse can you define a $_SESSION variable in a link? the reason I ask is because I need it to be defined by where the user clicks on an image map. EX: <area shape="rect" coords="502,583,536,651" alt="D06" href="roomdata.php?loc=D06" />

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use:

```
<?php
    header('Location: roomdata.php?loc='.$loc);
?>
```

Comment: in this case you could use single quotes

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if( isset($_GET['loc']))?>

<?php $loc = $_GET["loc"];?>

TRY

<?php
    if( isset($_GET['loc'])){
        $loc = $_GET["loc"];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Yes, @LifeByte really needs to stop wrapping every line in `<?php ?>` tags. It is confusing, unnecessary, and will likely introduce extraneous whitespace into the output that will conflict with calls like `header()`.

Comment: yes, and of course do make sure a GET var with the key loc is actually passed :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, are you sure `$loc` is defined at this point?

Regarding `'` and `"`:

```
$value = "derp";
echo "the value is:\t$value";
//output: the value is:     derp

echo 'the value is:\t$value';
//output: the value is:\t$value
```